# link field does not validate http://

Tags: entities

I have link CCK field but the field does not validate "HTTP://" like this
[image]

how I can make the validate "HTTP://" for this field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do it by using this model [advanced_link](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_link) in drupal model, thanks all

Answer (score 4):

In drupal 7, go to your content type in:

**/admin/structure/types/manage/yourcontentype/fields/**

Edit your field and check if it is validating your URL. I have attached a picture for better explanation.

[image: Link]

Answer (score 3):

I would have a look at [clientside validation](http://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation). Alternatively you could use hook_form_alter to add in your own validation by changing $form['#validate'] to point to your custom validator.

If you go down the programtic route and just want to check the format you could use PHP FILTER_VALIDATE_URL Filter function which would return true if its a url. Additionally, I would look at using CURL to verify the url actually exists.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In the D6 version at least, there is a checkbox for validating the link:

[image]

so I'd first make sure that's checked on your site before any custom coding...